# Python3 argp different behavior for strings passed from terminal and passed in config

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, encode, unicode-string

When I execute the below code in Python v3.9

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="whatever", description='test argp')
parser.add_argument("--test",  help="Test")    

pargs =  parser.parse_args('--test something')   # Line A
#pargs =  parser.parse_args()                    # Line B  "program --test something"
```

I get the below error. But the code works fine if I use Line B and input the same string from the terminal.

```
C:\usr\dev\test>\usr\apps\python\3.9\python.exe test.py --test tttt
usage: whatever [-h] [--test TEST]
whatever: error: unrecognized arguments: - - t e s t   s o m e t h i n g
```

I notice the apparent space between the characters, so looks like the string from the terminal is ascii, but the python string is passed as unicode.

I tried to encode, but it still does not work

```
pargs =  parser.parse_args('--test something'.encode('ascii'))
```

```
C:\usr\dev\test>\usr\apps\python\3.9\python.exe test.py --test tttt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\usr\dev\test\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    pargs =  parser.parse_args('--test something'.encode('ascii'))
  File "C:\usr\apps\python\3.9\lib\argparse.py", line 1818, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\usr\apps\python\3.9\lib\argparse.py", line 1851, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\usr\apps\python\3.9\lib\argparse.py", line 1895, in _parse_known_args
    option_tuple = self._parse_optional(arg_string)
  File "C:\usr\apps\python\3.9\lib\argparse.py", line 2182, in _parse_optional
    if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

May be this is answered before, but i cant find any solutions. Can someone help please ?

Comment: `parse_args` normally works with `sys.argv[1:]`.  If given something else that isn't already a list (of strings), it does `list(argv)`.  That's why it tried to parse `['-', '-', 't',... ]`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, after some more research.
Here is the working version:

```
import argparse
import shlex

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="whatever", description='test argp')
parser.add_argument("--test", help="Test")    

cmd = '--test something'
cmdline = shlex.split(cmd)
         
pargs =  parser.parse_args(cmdline)
```

Comment: `a string`.split()` is usually enough, but the `shlex` version is more accurate.  The argparse docs has lots of examples.